# Normalization/standardization impact on T-SNE and K-means

Tags: clustering, normalization, k-means, standardization, tsne

I have a dataset of 20K samples on 27 features that I am trying to cluster with k-means. The dataset is in its majority rather sparse, i.e. 98% of samples have a single nonzero value in one of its features, but with different amplitudes. I have two issues here:

1. I believe there is not much information gain in clustering this subset as nothing really connect them besides maybe "nonzeroness" on a given feature, but that is not what I want here. Instead, the 2% is quite interesting, because there is features' correlation in there. I am seeing complete different clustering results according to whether I do standardization or normalization. Standardization groups almost this 98% group in 1 cluster, detect high amplitude single-features classes, and find interesting connections among the dense samples. Normalization almost groups everything, feature based, i.e. the 98% gets into several clusters depending on their nonzero feature. I have got few interpretations about that, but they are still not fully decisive to me. Is somebody interested in providing an explanation to be discussed?
2. The second part of the question is that I am trying to visualize these samples with 2D t-SNE projection. Again here, the discussion is about whether to standardize or normalize as a preprocessing step. I believe since t-SNE is multi-dimensional local distance-preserving method, it is quite interesting to standardize so large variances do not win over. Also, in the logic of doing K-means that is based on Euclidian distances, standardization is the way to go. However, this is not at all what I am seeing and I did not manage to produce a single visualization where the standardized clustering made sense. Instead, normalization always seemed to perform well. Does anyone get why this is happening or maybe was confronted to the same problem? I provide below the visualization figures according to distinct preprocessing steps for t-SNE projection and k-means.

[image: No preprocessing before projection, normalization before clustering]

[image: No preprocessing before projection, standardization before clustering]

[[image: Standardization before projection, normalization before clustering 3]

[image: Standardization before projection, standardization before clustering]

[image: Normalization before projection, normalization before clustering]

[image: Normalization before projection, standardization before clustering]

[image: Standardization+normalization before projection, normalization before clustering]

[image: Standardization+normalization before projection, standardization before clustering]